# Resolve each ObjectId in an array field to an object from another collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is quite a specific problem and I have been trawling stack overflow for hours looking for a solution.

I have two collections:

events:

```
{   
    _id : ObjectId,
    title : $title,
    other fields etc...,
    artist : ObjectId,
    targets : [ObjectId,ObjectId,ObjectId]
}
```

artists:

```
{   
    _id : ObjectId,
    name : $name,
    other fields etc...
}
```

each event has a field with multiple targets, saved as ObjectId's. I need a query using some combination of aggregation and `$lookup` to return an event (matched with `.find( { _id : ObjectId_of_event } )` with each target resolved to an object

it would hopefully resemble this:

```
{   _id : ObjectId,
    title : $title,
    other fields...,
    targets : [ {   
                   _id : ObjectId_1,
                   name : $name,
                   other fields etc...
                },
                {   
                   _id : ObjectId_2,
                   name : $name,
                   other fields etc...
                },
                {   
                   _id : ObjectId_3,
                   name : $name,
                   other fields etc...
                } ]
}
```

I have tried aggregating, applying a `$lookup` and then using `$group` in the mongodb pipeline but have not found a way to keep all of the targets in the targets array and just resolve each ObjectId.

//edit extra info

the query I am currently running:

```
db.collection("events").aggregate([
     { $match: { _id : object } }, 
     { $lookup : { 
                  from: "artists",
                  localField: "artist",
                  foreignField: "_id",
                  as: "artist_object" 
     }},
     { $unwind : "$targets"},
     { $lookup : { 
                  from: "artists",
                  localField: "targets",
                  foreignField: "_id",
                  as: "targets_objects" 
                 }} 
      }} ]).toArray(function(queryErr, main_event) etc...
```

which returns:

```
     [ { event : { _id : ObjectId,
                  title : $title,
                  artist : ObjectId,
                  targets : { artist_object_of_first_target }
                  artist_object : { artist object }
       },
       { event : { _id : ObjectId,
                  title : $title,
                  artist : ObjectId,
                  targets : { artist_object_of_second_target }
                  artist_object : { artist object }
       },
       { event : { _id : ObjectId,
                  title : $title,
                  artist : ObjectId,
                  targets : { artist_object_of_third_target }
                  artist_object : { artist object }
       }]
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

From mongodb version `3.3.4` you can now pass array to `localField` in `$lookup` which in your case is `targets` so you get object from artists collection with same _id as ObjectId in targets array. Also you first need to match documents from events by _id.

```
db.collection('events').aggregate([
    {$match: {
        _id: ObjectId("58d7deaf20362d084071ea0e")
    }},
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'artists',
        localField: 'targets',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'targets'
    }}
    ]).toArray().then(result => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4))
    })
```

Also don't forget to get `ObjectId` from mongodb so you can use it in query.

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
var ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectId;
```

Final result will look like this.

```
[{
  "_id": "58d7deaf20362d084071ea0e",
  "title": "Event 1",
  "targets": [{
    "_id": "58d7ded4785cdf10a8847f78",
    "name": "Artist 1"
  }, {
    "_id": "58d7dedf8f37180f0ce1db38",
    "name": "Artist 4"
  }]
}]
```

Comment: thanks so much for the response so quickly, I may have been too broad in explaining what i have already tried, I have given this a go but it requires a {$unwind : $targets } in there to make each object in the array accessible. However doing this returns three separate but identical objects each with a different  target object in thei targets field

Comment: db.collection("events").aggregate([{ $match: { _id : object } },  { $lookup : { from: "artists",localField: "aggressor", foreignField: "_id",  as: "aggressor_object" }}, { $unwind : "$targets"}, { $lookup : {   from: "artists",
                                                                    localField: "targets", foreignField: "_id",as: "targets_objects" }} }} ]).toArray(function(queryErr, main_event) etc... is what I am currently running.

Comment: Like i said in answer from version `3.3.4` you don't have to use `$unwind` and you can just pass array.

Comment: but if i dont use unwind i get { etc ... targets : [] etc... } an empty array

Comment: I tested it with collections and document structures you provided and it works fine, can you copy-paste your code in jsfiddle so i can take a look, also check your mongodb version.

Comment: are there complications because i am doing two $lookups in one query? just edited my question to show you what i am currently doing and what it returns. also using a mongodb service from mlab so that shouldnt be the problem

Comment: i dont know how to hook mongo up to jsfiddle?

Comment: `:)` You don't need to do that, you just need to show me that part where you execute code i wrote in answer, because it should be working.

Comment: i cant show you the actual results but as i said before, if i run the query you wrote, target_objects ( which should contain an array of resolved artist objects) is empty

Comment: do you think you could recreate the query in the question with the multiple $lookups to see if that returns the same result as me?

Comment: If you run query with just `$match` stage without `$lookup` do you get any results?

Comment: yeah of course, an object is returned, which has an empty target_objects field

Comment: If you executed query with just `$match` there shouldn't be `target_objects` field at all because there is no such field in original object, you should just get object from events collection with same id

Comment: yeah youre right, if there are no $lookups there is no target_objects field. if i run the query you wrote with the $lookup it returns an empty array as the target_objects field :)

Comment: so anyway if you read the query i wrote above what do you think im doing wrong?